# Flutter health plugin "Authorization not granted"

Tags: flutter, google-fit

I am using the flutter [health](https://pub.dev/packages/health) package. It is working fine on iOS but on Android, it kept saying "Authorization is not granted".
I followed the [example](https://pub.dev/packages/health) to get the fitness API on the google developer console and OAuth Client ID. But I don't know how to set it in my flutter app if it is needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it working by following [this advice](https://github.com/cph-cachet/flutter-plugins/issues/336#issuecomment-841665698) on the package Github repo. But I am open to more answers. Thanks

[Updated]
This solution can cause conflict and raise the "version solving failed" exception when using it together with the location package.

The best way, for now, is to use health: 3.0.4 as a workaround.